# How does the SVD solve the least squares problem?

Tags: matrices, optimization, least-squares, svd, quadratic-programming

How do I prove that the least-squares solution for $$\text{minimize} \quad \|Ax-b\|_2$$ is $A^{+} b$, where $A^{+}$ is the pseudoinverse of $A$?

Comment: another related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2210789/is-the-pseudoinverse-matrix-the-solution-to-the-least-squares-problem

Comment: also related: https://www.quora.com/Does-the-pseudo-inverse-minimize-the-least-squares-problem

Comment: Let $A \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$. The best definition of the pseudoinverse $A^+$ is that $A^+$ takes a vector $b \in \mathbb R^m$ as input and returns as output the least norm solution to $Ax = \hat b$, where $\hat b$ is the projection of $b$ onto the column space of $A$.

Answer (score 36):

The Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse is a natural consequence from applying the singular value decomposition to the least squares problem. The SVD resolves the least squares problem into two components: (1) a range space part which can be minimized, and (2) a null space term which cannot be removed - a residual error. The first part will naturally create the pseudoinverse solution.

**Define SVD**

Start with a nonzero matrix $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}_{\rho}$, where the matrix rank $1\le\rho<m$ and $\rho<n$. The singular value decomposition, guaranteed to exist, is
$$
\mathbf{A}
= 
\mathbf{U} \, 
\Sigma \, 
\mathbf{V}^{*} 
=
\left[
  \begin{array}{cc}
    \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}} &
    \color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}
  \end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    \mathbf{S} & \mathbf{0} \\
    \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0}
  \end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} \\
    \color{red}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{N}}}^{*}
  \end{array}
\right].
$$
The codomain matrix $\mathbf{U}\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times m}$, and the domain matrix $\mathbf{V}\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ are unitary: 
$$
\mathbf{U}^{*}\mathbf{U} = \mathbf{U}\mathbf{U}^{*} = \mathbf{I}_{m}, \quad 
\mathbf{V}^{*}\mathbf{V} = \mathbf{V}\mathbf{V}^{*} = \mathbf{I}_{n}.
$$
The column vectors of the domain matrices provide orthonormal bases for the four fundamental subspaces:
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
%
 matrix & subspace \\\hline
%
  \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}}\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times\rho} & 
      \color{blue}{\mathcal{R}\left(\mathbf{A}\right)} =
          \text{span}\left\{\color{blue}{u_{1}},\dots,\color{blue}{u_{\rho}}\right\}\\
%
  \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times\rho} &
      \color{blue}{\mathcal{R}\left(\mathbf{A}^{*}\right)} =
          \text{span}\left\{\color{blue}{v_{1}},\dots,\color{blue}{v_{\rho}}\right\}\\
%
  \color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times m-\rho} &
     \color{red}{\mathcal{N}\left(\mathbf{A^{*}}\right)} =
          \text{span}\left\{\color{red}{u_{\rho+1}},\dots,\color{red}{u_{m}}\right\}\\
%
  \color{red}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{N}}}\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n-\rho} &
     \color{red}{\mathcal{N}\left(\mathbf{A}\right)} =
          \text{span}\left\{\color{red}{v_{\rho+1}},\dots,\color{red}{v_{n}}\right\}\\
%
\end{array}
$$
There are $\rho$ singular values which are ordered and real:
$$
  \sigma_{1} \ge \sigma_{2} \ge \dots \ge \sigma_{\rho}>0,
$$
and are the square root of non-zero eigenvalues of the product matrices $\mathbf{A}^{*}\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^{*}$. These singular values form the diagonal matrix of singular values
$$
\mathbf{S} 
= \text{diagonal} (\sigma_{1},\sigma_{2},\dots,\sigma_{\rho}) 
= 
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
\sigma_{1} \\
& \ddots \\
&& \sigma_{\rho}
\end{array} \right]
\in\mathbb{R}^{\rho\times\rho}.
$$
The $\mathbf{S}$ matrix is embedded in the sabot matrix $\Sigma\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ whose shape insures conformability.

**Define least squares solution**

Consider that the linear system
$$
\mathbf{A} x = b
$$
does not have an exact solution, so we generalize the question and ask for the best solution vector $x$. Using the $2-$norm, we ask for the least squares solution which minimizes $r^{2}(x) = \lVert \mathbf{A} x - b \rVert_{2}^{2}$, the sum of the squares of the residual errors:
$$
 x_{LS} = 
\left\{ 
  x \in \mathbb{C}^{n} \colon
  \big\lVert
    \mathbf{A} x - b
  \big\rVert_{2}^{2}
  \text{ is minimized}
\right\}
$$

**Exploit SVD - resolve range and null space components**

A useful property of unitary transformations is that they are invariant under the $2-$norm. For example
$$
\lVert \mathbf{V} x \rVert_{2} = \lVert x \rVert_{2}.
$$ 
This provides a freedom to transform problems into a form easier to manipulate. In this case, 
$$
\begin{align}
r\cdot r &=
\lVert
 \mathbf{A}x - b
\rVert_{2}^{2}
=
\lVert
 \mathbf{U}^{*}\left(\mathbf{A}x - b \right)
\rVert_{2}^{2}
=
\lVert
 \mathbf{U}^{*}\left(\mathbf{U} \, 
\Sigma \, 
\mathbf{V}^{*}x - b \right)
\rVert_{2}^{2} \\
&=
\lVert
 \Sigma \mathbf{V}^{*} x - \mathbf{U}^{*} b
\rVert_{2}^{2}.
\end{align}
$$
Switching to the block form separates the range and null space terms,
$$
\begin{align}
r^{2}(x) 
&= 
\big\lVert
 \Sigma \mathbf{V}^{*} x - \mathbf{U}^{*} b
\big\rVert_{2}^{2}
=
\Bigg\lVert
%
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    \mathbf{S} & \mathbf{0} \\
    \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0}
  \end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} \\
    \color{red}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{N}}}^{*}
  \end{array}
\right]
%
x - 
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} \\
    \color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}^{*}
  \end{array}
\right]
b
\Bigg\rVert_{2}^{2} \\
  &=
\big\lVert
\mathbf{S}
\color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} x - 
\color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} b
\big\rVert_{2}^{2}
+
\big\lVert
\color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}^{*} b
\big\rVert_{2}^{2}
\end{align}
$$

The separation between the range and null space contributions to the total error is also a separation between components which are under control and not controlled. The vector which we control is the solution vector $x$ which appears only in the (blue) range space term. What remains is the (red) null space term, a residual error.

**Solve and recover Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse**

Select the vector $x$ in the range space term which forces that term to $0$:
$$
\mathbf{S}
\color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} x - 
\color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} b
=
0
\qquad
\Rightarrow
\qquad
x = 
\color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}
\mathbf{S}^{-1}
\color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*}b.
$$
This is the **least squares solution** 
$$
  \color{blue}{x_{LS}} = \color{blue}{\mathbf{A}^{\dagger} b} 
= 
\color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}
\mathbf{S}^{-1}
\color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*}b
$$
using the thin SVD.

We are left with an error term which we cannot remove, a residual error, given by 
$$
  r^{2}\left(x_{LS}\right) = 
\big\lVert
\color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}^{*}} b
\big\rVert_{2}^{2},
$$
which quantifies the portion of the data vector $b$ residing in the null space.

Comment: what does R(A) mean? column space of A? or is it row space?

Comment: @Nina Kaprez: $\color{blue}{\mathcal{R}\left(\mathbf{A}\right)}$ is the range space of the matrix $\mathbf{A}$. It is the space spanned by the *column* vectors of $\mathbf{A}$. For more detail: [column space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_and_column_spaces#Column_space)

Comment: The final implication seems a little off. Doesn’t ${ \mathbf{S} \mathbf{V} _{\mathcal{R}} ^{*} x - \mathbf{U} _{\mathcal{R}} ^{*} b = 0 }$ only imply ${ \mathbf{V} _{\mathcal{R}} ^{*} x = \mathbf{S} ^{-1} \mathbf{U} _{\mathcal{R}} ^{*} b }$ ? Since ${ \mathbf{V} _{\mathcal{R}} }$ is ${ n \times \rho },$ this gives a family of solutions for ${ x }.$ As ${ x = \mathbf{V} _{\mathcal{R}} \mathbf{S} ^{-1} \mathbf{U} _{\mathcal{R}} ^{*} b }$ is a particular solution, the full solution set is ${ \text{(above solution)} + \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{V} _{\mathcal{R}} ^{*}) }$.

Answer (score 5):

First order condition:

$$\frac{d}{dx}||Ax-b||_2^2=\frac{d}{dx}(Ax-b)'(Ax-b)=A'(Ax-b)=0$$

Thus,

$$x=(A'A)^{-1}A'b=A^+b$$

Comment: What are your assumptions on $A$?

Comment: $A'A$ is invertible ($A$ has full column rank)

Comment: @d.k.o.I meant for a general case. $A$ can be rank deficient.

Comment: Check theorem 11.1.2 (page 446) : http://www.sci.utah.edu/~gerig/CS6640-F2012/Materials/pseudoinverse-cis61009sl10.pdf

Comment: @d.k.o. Please, could you explain why $\frac{d}{dx}(Ax-b)'(Ax-b)=A'(Ax-b)$? Why the derivative $d(x^T A^T)/dx=A^T$? A lot of thanks!

Comment: you should be explicit that your answer does not take care of $r<m$, $r<n$ because $A^T A$ is only invertible if $A$ is full column rank.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to realise is that the possible values of $Ax$ cover all and only the range of $A$: $\{Ax: x\in V\}=\mathrm{Range}(A)$.
This means that the problem $Ax=b$ is solvable if and only if $b\in\mathrm{Range}(A)$.

Now consider the more general case in which $b\in \mathrm{Range}(A)$ is not necessarily true, and thus the problem cannot be solved exactly. Because $A$ allows us to generate everything in $\mathrm{Range}(A)$ by an appropriate choice of $x$, it is then only natural that the $x$ that gives the best solution (in $\|\cdot\|_2$ norm) is the one such that $Ax$ equals the projection of $b$ onto $\mathrm{Range}(A)$. In other words, denoting with $\mathbb P_R$ the projector onto $\mathrm{Range}(A)$, we want $x$ such that
$$Ax=\mathbb P_R b.\tag A$$
With this choice of $x$, the distance between $Ax$ and $b$ is then
$$\|b-\mathbb P_R b\|_2=\|(I-\mathbb P_R)b\|_2.$$

Now, why does the SVD enters the discussion? Well, mostly because it provides an easy way to find the $x$ satisfying (A).

To see this, write the SVD in dyadic notation as
$$A=\sum_k s_k u_k v_k^*,\tag B$$
where $s_k>0$ are the singular values, and $\{u_k\}$ and $\{v_k\}$ are orthonormal bases for $\mathrm{Range}(A)$ and $A^{-1}(\mathrm{Range}(A)\setminus \{0\})=\mathrm{Ker}(A)_\perp$, respectively.
The expression (B) is equivalent to the maybe more common way to see the SVD, $A=UDV^\dagger$, with $v_k$ being the columns of $V$ and $u_k$ the columns of $U$.

The pseudo-inverse $A^+$ has a nice expression in terms of its SVD:
$$A^+=\sum_k s_k^{-1} v_k u_k^*. \tag C$$
With these expressions, you might notice how
$$A(A^+ y)=\sum_k u_k u_k^* y=\sum_k u_k\langle u_k,y\rangle=\mathbb P_R y.$$
Now, remember we want to get as close to $b$ as possible, and therefore are looking for some $y$ such that
$$A(A^+ y)=\mathbb P_R y=\mathbb P_R b.$$
This tells us that we want $y=b$, and thus $x=A^+ b$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the equation ${ Ax = b }$ where ${ A \in \mathbb{R} ^{m \times n} ,}$ ${ b \in \mathbb{R} ^{m} }.$ Goal is to find an approximate solution ${ \hat{x} \in \mathbb{R} ^{n} ,}$ one for which $${ \lVert A \hat{x} - b \rVert = \min _{x \in \mathbb{R} ^n} \lVert Ax - b \rVert}.$$ Such an ${ \hat{x} }$ need not be unique. For example, when ${ m = 1 }$ and ${ b = 0 }.$

We have two approaches, and the SVD approach gives an explicit solution.

**Without SVD**:

Pick any basis ${ \mathcal{B} = (v _1, \ldots, v _r) }$ of ${ \text{colsp}(A) }.$

One natural option for the basis is: Say the reduced row echelon form of ${ A }$ is ${ A ^{'} =  E _k \ldots E _1 A = (A ^{'} _1, \ldots, A ^{'} _{n}) ,}$ with pivot columns at positions ${ i _1 \lt \ldots \lt i _r }.$ So ${ (A  ^{'} _{i _1}, \ldots, A ^{'} _{i _r}) }$ is a basis of ${ \text{colsp}(A^{'}) }.$
Now ${ \mathscr{B} = (A _{i _1}, \ldots, A _{i _r}) }$ is a basis of ${ \text{colsp}(A) }$. [Since for any elementary matrix ${ E },$ ${ (M _{i _1}, \ldots, M _{i _r}) }$ is a basis of ${ \text{colsp}(M) }$ if and only if ${ (EM _{i _1}, \ldots, EM _{i _r}) }$ is a basis of ${ \text{colsp}(EM) }$].

We want an ${ \tilde{x} \in \mathbb{R} ^{r} }$ for which ${ \mathcal{B} \tilde{x} }$ (a generic point in ${ \text{colsp}(\mathcal{B}) = \text{colsp}(A) }$) is closest to ${ b }.$ For such an ${ \tilde{x} },$ we have that ${ b - \mathcal{B}\tilde{x} }$ is orthogonal to ${ \text{colsp}(\mathcal{B}) },$ that is ${ \mathcal{B} ^{T} (b - \mathcal{B} \tilde{x}) = 0},$ that is ${ \mathcal{B} ^{T} b = \mathcal{B} ^{T} \mathcal{B} \tilde{x} ,}$ that is ${ \tilde{x} = (\mathcal{B} ^T \mathcal{B}) ^{-1} \mathcal{B} ^{T} b }.$

So different choices of bases ${ \mathcal{B} }$ of ${ \text{colsp}(A) }$ give different points ${ \mathcal{B}\tilde{x} = \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{B} ^T \mathcal{B}) ^{-1} \mathcal{B} ^{T} b \in \text{colsp}(A) }$ closest to ${ b }.$ (Btw invertibility of ${ \mathcal{B} ^{T} \mathcal{B} }$ follows for eg from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4782937/303300)).

**With SVD**:

[Same as dantopa’s answer above]

Consider the notation from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4833056/303300). Substituting the SVD of ${ A }$ in ${ \lVert Ax - b \rVert ^2 }$ gives $${ \begin{align*} \lVert A x - b \rVert ^{2} &= \left\lVert \mathscr{U} \begin{pmatrix} \Sigma _r &0 \\ 0 &0 \end{pmatrix} \mathscr{V} ^{*} x   -  b  \right\rVert ^{2} \\ &= \left\lVert \mathscr{U} \left( \begin{pmatrix} \Sigma _r &0 \\ 0 &0 \end{pmatrix} \mathscr{V} ^{*} x  - \mathscr{U} ^{*} b \right) \right\rVert ^{2}  \\ &= \left\lVert \begin{pmatrix} \Sigma _r &0 \\ 0 &0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \mathscr{V} _{r} ^{*} \\ \mathscr{V} _{n-r} ^{*} \end{pmatrix} x - \begin{pmatrix} \mathscr{U} _{r} ^{*} \\ \mathscr{U} _{m-r} ^{*} \end{pmatrix} b \right\rVert ^{2} \\ &= \left\lVert \Sigma _{r} \mathscr{V} _{r} ^{*} x - \mathscr{U} _{r} ^{*} b \right\rVert ^{2} +  \left\lVert \mathscr{U} _{m-r} ^{*} b \right\rVert ^{2}. \end{align*} }$$

The minimisers of this quantity are precisely those ${ x }$ which satisfy ${ \Sigma _{r} \mathscr{V} _{r} ^{*} x - \mathscr{U} _{r} ^{*} b = 0 }$ that is $${ \mathscr{V} _{r} ^{*} x = \Sigma _{r} ^{-1} \mathscr{U} _{r} ^{*} b. }$$

Note ${ x = \mathscr{V} _{r}  \Sigma _{r} ^{-1} \mathscr{U} _{r} ^{*} b   }$ is a particular solution, hence the full solution set is $${ \begin{align*} x &\in  \mathscr{V} _{r}  \Sigma _{r} ^{-1} \mathscr{U} _{r} ^{*} b + \mathcal{N}(\mathscr{V} _r ^{*}) \\ &= A ^{\dagger} b + \text{span}(\mathscr{V} _{n-r}).   \end{align*} }$$

Especially, the set of minimisers is ${ (n-r) }$ dimensional.

Note ${ A ^{\dagger} b = \mathscr{V} _{r} \Sigma _{r} ^{-1} \mathscr{U} _{r} ^{*} b }$ is in ${ \text{span}(\mathscr{V} _r) }$ and hence is orthogonal to ${ \text{span}(\mathscr{V} _{n-r}) }.$ So amongst the minimisers ${ A ^{\dagger} b + \text{span}(\mathscr{V} _{n-r}) },$ the minimiser with least norm is ${ x = A ^{\dagger} b }.$