# Using pseudo inverse to solve least squares problem

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to find the least squares solution using the Pseudo=oinverse, min$_\mathbf x  $$_\in$$_\Bbb R$3||A$\mathbf x - \mathbf b$||$_2$, where

A= $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 5\\
1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 2\\
1 & 3 & 3\\
\end{bmatrix}$
 and $\mathbf b$=
$\begin{bmatrix}
3\\
5\\
7\\
-3\\
\end{bmatrix}$.

And the pseudo inverse $A^\dagger$ = ($A^T$$A$)$^{-1}$$A^T$.

How do we apply $A^\dagger$ to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A^\dagger b$ provides the vector $x$ that minimizes $\|Ax - b\|_2$ (in the case that $A^TA$ is invertible, this minimum is unique).  Thus, the solution to your problem will be 
$$
\|A(A^\dagger b) - b\|_2 = \|(AA^\dagger - I)b\|
$$

Comment: what is the proof that the pseudo-inverse minimizes the least square problem?

Comment: @Pinocchio a few proofs are given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/974193/81360)

Comment: thanks I will check it out! But before I do, super quick question (to make sure my point is addressed explicitly somewhere). Does pseudo-inverse minimize least squares even if the matrix is not full column nor full row rank? i.e. $r<n,r<m$

Comment: @Pinocchio here's the way to think about it: among the least-squares solutions to $Ax = b$, $x = A^\dagger b$ is the one with minimal $\|x\|$.  If $A$ has full column-rank, then there will be a unique least squares solution.  If $A$ has full row-rank, then every least squares solution will be an exact solution.