# A solution not quite adding up for Orthogonal Projection

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, gaussian-elimination

The solution that is not adding up is in the link below. Specifically, the answer provided by Chad. I really enjoyed his answer but couldn't comment (not enough reputation) on one aspect that was unclear.

[Difference between orthogonal projection and least squares solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1298261/difference-between-orthogonal-projection-and-least-squares-solution?newreg=40314d2455994946a1430fbe7eec1557)

So here is my understanding of his answer:

1. In Chad's scenario, we had a no solution or an inconsistent system as b is not in the Column space of A. Therefore, we are solving for Ax = p instead.
2. You use the projection formula to find p.
3. The p vector is in the column space of A ?
4. I can now solve the system via R-REF and get a solution set. This is where the problem is. For X1, I get a Column Vector of 1/2 and 0 not 1 and 0. Is there a possibility he made a mistake?
   I double checked using this site:
   https://matrix.reshish.com/gaussSolution.php

Greetings

Comment: Yes you are right, the solution set should have been $\left\{t \begin{bmatrix}-2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} +  \begin{bmatrix}1/2\\0\end{bmatrix} : t \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$.

Comment: Thanks. One other question. When I take the dot product of p and x, it does not quite result in 0 (orthogonal). I get -1 ? I guess it does make sense as we have to approximate?

Comment: In general it does not even make sense to take the dot product of $p$ and $x$. When $A$ is not square, $p$ and $x$ aren't even in the same space.

Comment: Yeah. That didn't make much sense. I ended up figuring out the vector component of b orthogonal to C(A) by subtracting b from the projection..and then when you take the dot product of the vector component of b orthogonal to C(A) with what spans the C(A)..you do get 0.

Comment: Yes that's right: $b-p$ is orthogonal to $C(A)$ in general.