# Least squares solutions for underdetermined system of rank $1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares, svd, projection, pseudoinverse

[image]

I'm doing problems from old exams, and my solutions don't add up with the professor's solution. The problem is as followed: **Find all least squares solutions of the linear system.** I checked my calculations are correct, I checked with my TI-82 STATS calculator and used the correct formulas. Can you check if this is correct or not?

Comment: Of course, finding least squares solutions of this linear system makes sense because of the inconsistency

Comment: Looks good to me. What is your professor's solution?

Comment: $(1  0  0)^T + s*(1  1  0)^T + t*(2  0  1)^T$, I cannot figure how he got positive 2 instead of -2, it should say $t*(-2  0  1)^T$

Comment: Your solution is correct. Your professor's must have a typo because $A\pmatrix{2\\ 0\\ 1}\ne0$.

Comment: Ah if so, I was going insane, thank you! I actually learned more by trying to figure out what I was doing wrong than his actual classes, and never thought about doing $A*(-2 0 1)^T=0$, would have saved me time. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Problem Statement

Modestly generalize the problem to consider *underdetermined matrices* of *rank one*.

#### Given

We are given the matrix $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times 3}$ and the data vector $b\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times 1}_{1}$
$$
\mathbf{A} = 
%
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr}
 2 & -2 & 4 \\
 -1 & 1 & -2 \\
\end{array}
\right], \quad
%
b =
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 3 \\
 1 
\end{array}
\right]
%
$$
and the goal is to find the set least squares minimizers for
$$ \mathbf{A} x = b.$$

The matrix $\mathbf{A}$ has $m=2$ rows, $n=3$ columns, and rank $\rho=1$. (There a few ways to resolve the rank. For example, notice that the two rows are linearly dependent.)

#### Least squares solution

The set of least squares minimizers is defined as
$$ x_{LS} = \left\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^{3} \colon 
\lVert \mathbf{A} x_{LS} - b\rVert_{2}^{2} \text{ is minimized} \right\}.\tag{1}$$

#### Fundamental Theorem of Linear Algebra

The Fundamental Theorem of Linear Algebra provides fundamental insight. A matrix $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}_{\rho}$ induces for fundamental subspaces:
$$
\begin{align}
%
  \mathbf{C}^{n} = 
    \color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)} \oplus
    \color{red}{\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)} \\
%
  \mathbf{C}^{m} = 
    \color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)} \oplus
    \color{red} {\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)}
%
\end{align}
$$
(Blue denotes vectors in a $\color{blue}{range}$ space, red denotes vectors in a $\color{red}{null}$ space.)

Focus on the structure of the domain space. Because $\rho<n$, the null space is nontrivial:
$$ \color{red}{\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)} \ne \left\{ \mathbf{0} \right\}
$$

#### Observation

Examination of the target matrix reveals some salient facts.

1. The two rows of $\mathbf{A}$ are linearly dependent:
   $$ \mathbf{A}_{1:*} = -2 \mathbf{A}_{2:*}.$$
2. The corresponding range space is then
   $$ \color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)} = \text{span} \left\{ \color{blue}{\left[
   \begin{array}{r}
    1 \\
    -1 \\
   2 
   \end{array}
   \right]}
   \right\} \tag{2}$$
3. The rank plus nullity theorem, indicates that $\color{red}{\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)}$ will be spanned by two vectors.
4. The general solution will then contain a particular solution and a homogeneous solution:
   $$ x_{LS} = \color{blue}{x_{p}} + \color{red}{x_{h}}\tag{3}$$
5. The range space for the domain is
   $$ \color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)} = \text{span} \left\{ \color{blue}{\left[
   \begin{array}{r}
   2 \\
   -1
   \end{array}
   \right]}
   \right\} \tag{4}$$

---

### Solution via calculus

#### Particular solution

Because $\color{blue}{x_{p}} \in \color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)} $, we must have
$$ \color{blue}{x_{p}} = \alpha \color{blue}{
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  1 \\
 -1 \\
  2 
\end{array}
\right]
}
$$
with $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$. Finding the particular solution boilds down to solving for $\alpha$.

**Solve for $\alpha$**

Use the solution definition in $(1)$ to compute $\alpha$. First, compute the residual error vector:
$$ r(\alpha x) = \mathbf{A} (\alpha x) - b = 
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  12 \alpha - 3 \\
 -6\alpha - 1 
\end{array}
\right]
.$$
The total error is then
$$ r(\alpha x)\cdot r(\alpha x) = 180\alpha^{2} - 60\alpha +10.$$
Minimize the total error by minimizing this function with respect to $\alpha.$ Find the zero values of the first derivative.
$$ D_{\alpha} \left(180\alpha^{2} - 60\alpha +10 \right) = 0 \quad \implies \quad \alpha = \frac{1}{6}$$
Therefore the particular solution is
$$ \color{blue}{x_{p}} = \frac{1}{6} 
\color{blue}{
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  1 \\
 -1 \\
  2 
\end{array}
\right]
}$$
(The least total error is
$ 180\cdot\tfrac{1}{36} - 60\cdot\tfrac{1}{6} + 10 = 5.)$

#### Homogeneous solution

We can resolve the null space by Intelligent Guessing. We are looking for two linearly independent vectors orthogonal to $\color{blue}{x_{p}}$. Try these shapes for the null space vectors:
$$
\color{blue}{
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  1 \\
 -1 \\
  2 
\end{array}
\right]}
\cdot
\color{red}{
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
  * \\
  0 \\
  * 
\end{array}
\right]} =\mathbf{0}, 
\qquad
\color{blue}{
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  1 \\
 -1 \\
  2 
\end{array}
\right]}
\cdot
\color{red}{
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
  * \\
  * \\
  0 
\end{array}
\right]} =\mathbf{0}.
$$
Two such choices are
$$ 
\color{red}{v_{1}} = 
\color{red}{
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  -2 \\
  0 \\
  1 
\end{array}
\right]},
\qquad
\color{red}{v_{2}} = 
\color{red}{
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  1 \\
  1 \\
  0 
\end{array}
\right]}.
$$
We have resolved the null space
$$ \color{red}{\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)} = \text{span}
\left\{ \color{red}{v_{1}}, \color{red}{v_{2}} \right\}
= \text{span}
\left\{
\color{red}{
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  -2 \\
  0 \\
  1 
\end{array}
\right]},
\color{red}{
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  1 \\
  1 \\
  0 
\end{array}
\right]}
\right\}.$$
Homogeneous solutions will have the form
$$
\color{red}{x_{h}} = \beta \color{red}{v_{1}} + \gamma \color{red}{v_{2}}.
$$
where the constants $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are arbitrary.

The final solution is
$$
\boxed{
x_{LS} =
\color{blue}{x_{p}} +
\color{red}{x_{h}} =
\frac{1}{6} 
\color{blue}{
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  1 \\
 -1 \\
  2 
\end{array}
\right]
}
+
\beta
\color{red}{
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  -2 \\
  0 \\
  1 
\end{array}
\right]} 
+
\gamma
\color{red}{
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  1 \\
  1 \\
  0 
\end{array}
\right]}}
$$
(You can verify that $\lVert \mathbf{A} x_{LS} - b\rVert_{2}^{2} = 5$.)

---

### Solution via vector projection

#### Use projection to find $\color{blue}{b_{\mathcal{R}}}$

Because of the simplicity of the problem, it's easy to find the solution using projections. The trick is to resolve the data vector in range and null space components:
$$ b = \color{blue}{b_{\mathcal{R}}} + \color{red}{b_{\mathcal{N}}}, $$ as seen in the following plot.

[image: b resolution]

The vector $\color{blue}{b_{\mathcal{R}}}$ is projection of the data vector $b$ onto $\color{blue}{\mathcal{R}(\mathbf{A})}$. Pick a vector in the span,
$$
 \color{blue}{s} = 
\color{blue}{\left[
\begin{array}{r}
2 \\
-1
\end{array}
\right]}
$$
Compute the solution vector
$$ 
\color{blue}{b_{\mathcal{R}}}
=
b \cdot 
\frac{\color{blue}{s}}{\lVert \color{blue}{s} \rVert}
=
\color{blue}{
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
2 \\
-1
\end{array}
\right]}
$$

#### Solve the consistent linear system

With a data vector in the range space, the linear system is now consistent and can be solved with Gaussian-Jordan Elimination.
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
\mathbf{A} & \color{blue}{b_{\mathcal{R}}}
\end{array}
\right] 
& \to &
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
\mathbf{E_{A}} & R
\end{array}
\right] 
\\
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
 2 & -2 & 4 & 2 \\
 -1 & 1 & -2 & -1\\
\end{array}
\right]
& \to &
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
 1 & -1 & 2 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{array}
\right]
\end{array}
$$

#### Craft solution

The interpretation of the reduced matrix $\mathbf{E_{A}}$ is
$$
x - y + 2z = 1.
$$
To match the convention posed in the question, let
$$ y = s, \quad z = t$$ to recover
$$
x = s -2t + 1, \qquad s,t \in \mathbb{R}.
$$
The least squares minimizes are the set
$$
\boxed{
x_{LS} = 
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 s - 2t + 1 \\
 s \\
 t
\end{array}
\right]}.
$$
This represents the complete set of minimizers without resolving the range and null space components $\color{blue}{x_{p}} + \color{red}{x_{h}}.$

To connect the pieces, note that the values $s=-\tfrac{1}{6}$, $t=\tfrac{1}{3}$ produce $\color{blue}{x_{p}}$.

---

### Solution via normal equations

The normal equations will not produce a particular solution, but they will provide the set of least squares minimizers.

The product matrix is singular:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\mathbf{A}^{*}\mathbf{A} x 
& = &
\mathbf{A}^{*} b 
\\
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr}
 5 & -5 & 10 \\
 -5 & 5 & -10 \\
 10 & -10 & 20 \\
\end{array}
\right]
& = &
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
  5 \\
 -5 \\
 10
\end{array}
\right]
\end{array}
$$
Because rank$\left(\mathbf{A}\right) = 1$, the product matrix is also rank 1 and offers no inverse. The usual solution path
$$
\color{blue}{x_{p}} = \left( \mathbf{A}^{*}\mathbf{A}\right)^{-1}
\mathbf{A}^{*} b
$$
is not available.

However, Gauss-Jordan elimination of the normal equations produces
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
\mathbf{A}^{*}\mathbf{A} & \mathbf{A}^{*} b
\end{array}
\right] 
& \to &
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
\mathbf{E_{A}} & R
\end{array}
\right] 
\\
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
 5 & -5 & 10 & 5 \\
 -5 & 5 & -10 & -5 \\
 10 & -10 & 20 & -10 \\
\end{array}
\right]
& \to &
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
 1 & -1 & 2 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{array}
\right]
\end{array}
$$
This is the same result from the previous solution.

---

### Solution via singular value decomposition

The SVD will provide the pseudoinverse matrix needed by $\color(blue){x_{p}}$ and the null space projector for $\color(red){x_{h}}$.

For derivations, refer to
[How does the SVD solve the least squares problem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/772039/how-does-the-svd-solve-the-least-squares-problem/2173715#2173715).

#### General solution for the least squares problem

The general solution for the least squares problem in $(1)$ is
$$
x_{LS} = \color{blue}{x_{p}} + \color{red}{x_{h}} = \underbrace{\mathbf{A}^{\dagger}b\vphantom{\big|}}_{\color{blue}{x_{p}}} + 
\underbrace{\left( \mathbf{I}_{n} -  \mathbf{A}^{\dagger} \mathbf{A}\right) y}_{\color{red}{x_{h}}}, \qquad y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}
$$

#### Singular value decomposition form

The form of the [singular value decomposition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1537880/what-forms-does-the-moore-penrose-inverse-take-under-systems-with-full-rank-ful) for this rank deficient problem is
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{A} &= \mathbf{U} \, \Sigma \, \mathbf{V}^{*}
= 
% U 
 \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 
 \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}(\mathbf{A})}} & \color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{A}^{*})}} 
 \end{array} \right] 
% Sigma 
 \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 
\mathbf{S} & \mathbf{0} \\ 
 \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} 
 \end{array} \right] 
% V 
\left[ \begin{array}{l}
  \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}(\mathbf{A}^{*})}^{*}} \\
  \color{red}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{A})}^{*}}
\end{array} \right]
\end{align}
$$

#### Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse matrix form

The corresponding Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse matrix is
$$
\begin{align}
%%
  \mathbf{A}^{\dagger} &= \mathbf{V} \, \Sigma^{\dagger} \, \mathbf{U}^{*}
= 
% U 
 \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 
 \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}(\mathbf{A}^{*})}} & 
 \color{red}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{A})}} 
 \end{array} \right] 
% Sigma 
 \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 
\mathbf{S}^{-1} & \mathbf{0} \\ 
 \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} 
 \end{array} \right] 
% V 
\left[ \begin{array}{l}
  \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}(\mathbf{A})}^{*}} \\
  \color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{A}^{*})}^{*}}
\end{array} \right]
\end{align}
$$

#### Computing the SVD

Computational details can be found in [Computing the SVD](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2287795/svd-and-the-columns-i-did-this-wrong-but-it-seems-that-it-still-works-why/2297254#2297254), and examples in [Calculating SVD by hand: resolving sign ambiguities in the range vectors.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1805191/calculating-svd-by-hand-resolving-sign-ambiguities-in-the-range-vectors/2239200#2239200), and, [Need to multiply by -1 for a SVD to work?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2043233/need-to-multiply-by-1-for-a-svd-to-work/2195331#2195331).

**Singular value spectrum**
The first step is to compute the singular values, which are the square roots of the ordered, non-zero, eigenvalues to the product matrix: $$\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^{*} = 6
\left[
\begin{array}{rr}
 4 & -2 \\
 -2 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right].$$
Pulling out the scaling factor of $6$ is not required, it's a personal peccadillo to simply hand calculations. Proceeding, the characteristic polynomial for the scaled eigenvalues $\Lambda$ is
$$
p(\Lambda) = \det
\left[
\begin{array}{rr}
 4-\Lambda & -2 \\
 -2 & 1-\Lambda \\
\end{array}
\right]
=
\Lambda(\Lambda - 5)
$$
The scaled and ordered eigenvalue spectrum is
$$
\Lambda \left( \mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^{*} \right)  = \left\{ 5, 0\right\}
$$
Restore the original scale of the eigenvalues using $\lambda = 6 \Lambda$, and take the square root:
$$
\sigma = \sqrt{\lambda} = \sqrt{30}.
$$

**Resolve**$\ \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}$

As there is but one vector in the domain,
$$
\color{blue}{\mathbf{V_{\mathcal{R}}}} = \frac{1}{6}
\color{blue}{\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  1 \\
 -1 \\
  2
\end{array}
\right]}
$$

**Resolve**$\ \color{blue}{\mathbf{U_{\mathcal{R}}}}$

The final step is
$$
\color{blue}{\mathbf{U_{\mathcal{R}}}} = \frac{1}{\sigma}\mathbf{A} \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}} =
\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}
\color{blue}{\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 -2 \\
  1
\end{array}
\right]}
$$

#### Assemble the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse matrix

Using the thin SVD, the pseudoinverse matrix is
$$
\mathbf{A}^{\dagger} = \frac{1}{30}
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  2 & -1\\
 -2 &  1\\
  4 & -2
\end{array}
\right].
$$

#### Particular solution

The particular solution is the least squares solution of least norm and is computed using the pseudoinverse matrix:
$$\color{blue}{x_{p}} = \mathbf{A}^{\dagger} b = \frac{1}{6} 
\color{blue}{
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  1 \\
 -1 \\
  2 
\end{array}
\right]
}, $$
as expected.

#### Homogeneous solution

**Assemble the projector onto** $\ \color{red}{\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)}$

The homogeneous term is handled by the projector onto $\color{red}{\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)} $. Start with the projector onto the range space $\color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)}$:
$$
\mathbf{P}_{\color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)}} = \frac{1}{6}
\left[
\begin{array}{rrc}
  1 &  -1 & 2 \\
 -1 &   1 & 2 \\
  2 &  -2 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
The projector needed for the least squares solution is the projector onto the orthogonal complement of $\color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)}$: the projector onto the null space $\color{red}{\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)}$. This projector  is
$$
\mathbf{P}_{\color{red}{\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)}} =
\mathbf{I}_{3} - \mathbf{P}_{\color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)}}
$$

#### Final solution

Using the SVD, the least squares solution set is given by
$$
\boxed{
x_{LS} = \color{blue}{x_{p}} + \color{red}{x_{h}} =
%% 
\mathbf{A}^{\dagger}b + 
\left( \mathbf{I}_{n} -  \mathbf{A}^{\dagger} \mathbf{A}\right) y
=
\frac{1}{6}
\color{blue}{
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  1 \\
 -1 \\
  2 
\end{array}
\right]}
+
\frac{1}{6}
\left[
\begin{array}{rcr}
  5 &  1 & -2 \\
  1 &  5 &  2\\
 -2 &  2 &  2
\end{array}
\right]y
, \qquad y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}}
$$

Comment: What a great answer!