# Need to multiply by -1 for a SVD to work?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd

I'm trying to do a singular value decomposition ($A = USV^T$) of the following matrix:

$A = \begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$

First of all I calculate $A^TA$ and $AA^T$ which in this case is the same: $\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$

Now I get the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of the previous matrix, which are
$\frac{3 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\frac{3 - \sqrt{5}}{2}$. The eigenvectors are [$\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$, 1] and [$\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}$, 1].

Let's define $\phi = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$

I can now construct both U and V with the normalized eigenvectors, which are orthogonal matrices:
$U = V = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{\phi}{\sqrt{\phi^2 + 1}}&\frac{1 - \phi}{\sqrt{(1 - \phi)^2 + 1}}\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{\phi^2 + 1}}&\frac{1/}{\sqrt{(1 - \phi)^2 + 1}}\end{bmatrix}$

Finally, I can calculate S which is the diagonal matrix with square roots of the eigenvalues of $AA^T$:
$S = \begin{bmatrix}\phi&0\\0&1-\phi\end{bmatrix}$

If I now calculate $USV^T$ I'm not getting A! I however realized that if I multiply the second column of V by -1 I then get A when doing $USV^T$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In this case I think they are, because $AA^T = A^TA$, am I wrong?

Comment: @Moo could you please tell me where u comes from?

Answer (score 1):

There is no advantage in computing the SVD of a real symmetric matrix instead of the symmetric eigenvalue decomposition. The natural decomposition
for a symmetric matrix is the symmetric eigenvalue decomposition  (SED) and not the SVD. Everything which can be done using the SVD of a symmetric matrix can be done using the SED provided the eigenvalues are ordered such that the absolute values of the eigenvalues are in the non-increasing order.

The main aim of the SVD is NOT to compute products such as $A^tA$ and $AA^t$. The computation of such products is considered as the worst "sin" one can do by numerical analysts.

However, if you insists that you would like to compute the SVD of a symmetric matrix then you may follow the following steps. I will be using numbers not symbolic variables. In any case, symbolic variables are difficult to handle with large matrices.

(a) Compute the SEP of the matrix $A$. This is given by
$$
A = U \Lambda U^t
$$
where 
$$
U = \left[ \begin{array}{rr}
     0.5257 &-0.8507 \\
     -0.8507 & -0.5257
\end{array}
    \right] ,\;\;\;
\Lambda = \left[ \begin{array}{rr}
     -0.6180 & 0 \\
     0  & 1.6180
\end{array}
    \right] .
$$

(b) Order the eigenvalues such that the absolute values are
non-decreasing.
$$
\Lambda = \left[ \begin{array}{rr}
      1.6180 & 0 \\
     0  & -0.6180
\end{array}
    \right] .
$$
Because of the permutation, we have to apply the same to the eigenvector matrix. In that case, the new matrix $U$ is given by
$$
U = \left[ \begin{array}{rr}
     -0.8507 & 0.5257 \\
     -0.5257 & -0.8507 
\end{array}
    \right] .
$$
 Note that, $A = U\Lambda U^t$ even after the reordering of the eigenvalues. That is,
$$
A = \left[ \begin{array}{rr}
     -0.8507 & 0.5257 \\
     -0.5257 & -0.8507 
\end{array}
    \right] 
\left[ \begin{array}{rr}
      1.6180 & 0 \\
     0  & -0.6180
\end{array}
    \right] 
 \left[ \begin{array}{rr}
     -0.8507 & -0.5257 \\
     0.5257 & -0.8507 
\end{array}
    \right].
$$

(c) Singular values are always non-negative. We negate the second eigenvalue and to compensate that negate the second row of $U^t$. Thus,

$$
A = \left[ \begin{array}{rr}
     -0.8507 & 0.5257 \\
     -0.5257 & -0.8507 
\end{array}
    \right] 
 \left[ \begin{array}{rr}
      1.6180 & 0 \\
     0  & 0.6180
\end{array}
    \right] 
 \left[ \begin{array}{rr}
     -0.8507 & -0.5257 \\
     -0.5257 & 0.8507 
\end{array}
    \right] 
$$
Thus, the SVD is of the symmetric matrix is given by
$$
A = U \Sigma V^t
$$
where
$$
U = \left[ \begin{array}{rr}
     -0.8507 & 0.5257 \\
     -0.5257 & -0.8507 
\end{array}
    \right] , \;\;\;
 \Sigma = \left[ \begin{array}{rr}
      1.6180 & 0 \\
     0  & 0.6180
\end{array}
    \right] ,\;\;\;
 V = \left[ \begin{array}{rr}
     -0.8507 & -0.5257 \\
     -0.5257 & 0.8507 
\end{array}
    \right] 
$$

We have demonstrated how to get the SVD of a symmetric matrix from the SED. This can be done for any symmetric matrix, small or large. Note that the columns of $U$ and $V$ are identical except perhaps for a signature change.

Answer (score 0):

@Vini provides a good solution. Another presentation1 follows.

Definition of the singular value decomposition:
$$
  \mathbf{A} = \mathbf{U} \, \Sigma \, \mathbf{V}^{*}
$$
$$
%
\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}_{\rho}, \quad
%
\mathbf{U} \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times m}, \quad
%
\mathbf{V} \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}, \quad
%
\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}, \quad
%
\mathbf{S} \in \mathbb{R}^{\rho\times\rho}
%
$$
The domain matrices are unitary:
$$
\begin{align}
 \mathbf{U}^{*} \mathbf{U} &= \mathbf{U} \, \mathbf{U}^{*} = \mathbf{I}_{m} \\
 \mathbf{V}^{*} \mathbf{V} &= \mathbf{V} \, \mathbf{V}^{*} = \mathbf{I}_{n}
\end{align}
$$
For this problem $m=n=\rho=2$ and both nullspaces are trivial.

**1 Compute product matrix**

$$
\mathbf{A}^{*} \mathbf{A} =
%
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
=
%
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

**2 Resolve eigensystem**

$$
\lambda \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \mathbf{A} \right) = 
\frac{1}{2} \left( 1 \pm \sqrt{5} \right)
$$
The choice of eigenvectors involves a choice of sign. This is the origin of the sign ambiguities of the SVD. The signs are chosen here with the domain matrix $\mathbf{V}$ and they will imprint in the codomain matrix $\mathbf{U}$.
$$
  v_{1} = 
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{1}{2} \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right) \\
  1 
\end{array}
\right], \quad
%
 v_{2} = 
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{1}{2} \left(1 - \sqrt{5}\right) \\
  1 
\end{array}
\right]
$$

**3 Assemble $\Sigma$**

The singular values of $\mathbf{A}$ are the square roots of the nonzero eigenvalues of the product matrix:
$$
  \sigma 
  = \sqrt{\lambda \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \mathbf{A} \right)}
  = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left( 1 \pm \sqrt{5} \right)}.
$$
The eigenvalues are ordered:
$$
 \sigma_{1} \ge \sigma_{2} \gt 0
$$
The diagonal matrix of singular values is
$$
  \mathbf{S} = 
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 \sigma_{1} & 0 \\
 0 & \sigma_{2} \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
=
%
\frac{1}{2}
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 + \sqrt{5} & 0 \\
 0 & 1 - \sqrt{5} \\
\end{array}
\right].
$$
in the general case this matrix is embedded in a sabot matrix which guarantees conformability:
$$
  \Sigma =
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 \mathbf{S} & \mathbf{0} \\
 \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} \\
\end{array}
\right]
\in
\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}.
$$
Because both nullspace are trivial in this example, $\Sigma = \mathbf{S}.$

**4 Assemble domain matrix $\mathbf{V}$**

$$
\begin{align}
 \mathbf{V} =
%
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{v_{1}} {\lVert v_{1} \rVert} & \frac{v_{2}} {\lVert v_{2} \rVert}
\end{array}
\right]
%
&=
%
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{ \frac{1}{2} \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)}}
 \left[
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{1}{2} \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right) \\
  1 
\end{array}
\right] & 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{ \frac{1}{2} \left(5-\sqrt{5}\right)}}
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{1}{2} \left(1-\sqrt{5}\right) \\
  1 
\end{array}
\right]
\end{array}
\right] \\[5pt]
%
&= 
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 \sqrt{\frac{1}{10} \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)} & -\sqrt{\frac{1}{10} \left(5-\sqrt{5}\right)} \\
 \sqrt{\frac{1}{10} \left(5-\sqrt{5}\right)} & \sqrt{\frac{1}{10} \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)} \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\end{align}
%
$$

**5 Construct codomain matrix $\mathbf{U}$**

From the definition 
$$
\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{U} \, \mathbf{S} \, \mathbf{V}^{*} 
 \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad
 \mathbf{A} \, \mathbf{V} = \mathbf{S} \,\mathbf{U}
$$
Therefore
$$
  \mathbf{U}_{k} = \sigma_{k}^{-1} \left[ \mathbf{A} \, \mathbf{V} \right]_{k}
$$
After some algebra,
$$
 \mathbf{U} =
\left[
\begin{array}{rr}
 \sqrt{\frac{1}{10} \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)} & \sqrt{\frac{1}{10} \left(5-\sqrt{5}\right)} \\
 \sqrt{\frac{1}{10} \left(5-\sqrt{5}\right)} & -\sqrt{\frac{1}{10} \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)} \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

**Verify decomposition**
$$
\begin{align}
%
\mathbf{A} &= \mathbf{U} \, \mathbf{S} \, \mathbf{V}^{*} \\
% A
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
 &=
% U
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 \sqrt{\frac{1}{10} \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)} & \sqrt{\frac{1}{10} \left(5-\sqrt{5}\right)} \\
 \sqrt{\frac{1}{10} \left(5-\sqrt{5}\right)} & -\sqrt{\frac{1}{10} \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)} \\
\end{array}
\right]
% S
\frac{1}{2}
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 + \sqrt{5} & 0 \\
 0 & 1 - \sqrt{5} \\
\end{array}
\right]
% V*
\left[
\begin{array}{rr}
 \sqrt{\frac{1}{10} \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)} & \sqrt{\frac{1}{10} \left(5-\sqrt{5}\right)} \\
 -\sqrt{\frac{1}{10} \left(5-\sqrt{5}\right)} & \sqrt{\frac{1}{10} \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)} 
\end{array}
\right]
%
\end{align}
$$

**Compare to diagonalization**

$$
  \mathbf{A} = \mathbf{P} \, \mathbf{D} \, \mathbf{P}^{-1}
$$
The diagonal matrix $\mathbf{D}$ uses the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}$, diagonalizer $\mathbf{P}$ is constructed from eigenvectors of $\mathbf{A}$.
$$
%
 \mathbf{P} =
\frac{1}{2}
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right) & 2 \\
 \left(1-\sqrt{5}\right) & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right], \quad
%
 \mathbf{D} =
\frac{1}{2}
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 1+\sqrt{5} & 0 \\
 0 & 1-\sqrt{5} \\
\end{array}
\right], \quad
%
\mathbf{P}^{-1} =
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{5}}
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & -2 \\
 -1+\sqrt{5} & 1+\sqrt{5} \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
$$