# Moore Condition for m x n matrix

Tags: least-squares, pseudoinverse

I'm not sure how to prove any of this. The only thing that seems to be related to this is: [How does the SVD solve the least squares problem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/772039/how-does-the-svd-solve-the-least-squares-problem) but it does not answer any of the questions below

**3.32.** Prove that the pseudoinverse $\boldsymbol{A}^+$ of an $m\times n$ matrix $\boldsymbol A$, as defined using the SVD in Section 3.6.1, satisfies the following four properties, known as the *Moore-Penrose conditions*.

(a) $\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{A}^+\boldsymbol{A}=\boldsymbol{A}$.

(b) $\boldsymbol{A}^+\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{A}^+=\boldsymbol{A}^+$.

(c) $(\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{A}^+)^T=\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{A}^+$.

(d) $(\boldsymbol{A}^+\boldsymbol{A})^T=\boldsymbol{A}^+\boldsymbol{A}$.

Comment: A little bit difficult to answer without having section 3.6.1. I suppose $A^+$ and $A$ are defined in terms of the matrices commonly called $U,\Sigma,V$ in the SVD and that you are supposed to substitute in left and right hand sides and see if you can get them to be equal.

Comment: Please try and use less images of text in questions and more typeset content even if there probably was a good thought behind this time.

Comment: Please consider updating the title to use 'Moore-Penrose conditions'. This helps others to find your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{U} \, \Sigma \, \mathbf{V}^{*}, \qquad
\mathbf{A}^{+} = \mathbf{U} \, \Sigma^{+} \, \mathbf{V}^{*}
$$

**$\Sigma$ gymnastics**

The problem distills down to an exercise in $\Sigma$ gymnastics. The diagonal matrix $\mathbf{S}$ contains the ordered singular values has size $\rho \times \rho.$ Note $\mathbf{S}^{T} = \mathbf{S}.$ The inverse matrix has reciprocal values on the diagonal.

First step:
$$
\begin{align}
  \Sigma = 
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
  \mathbf{S} & \mathbf{0} \\
  \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} 
\end{array} \right]_{m\times n},  \qquad
%
  \Sigma^{T} = 
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
  \mathbf{S} & \mathbf{0} \\
  \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} 
\end{array} \right]_{n\times m},  \qquad
%
  \Sigma^{+} = 
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
  \mathbf{S}^{-1} & \mathbf{0} \\ 
  \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} 
\end{array} \right]_{n\times m}
%
\end{align}
$$
Second step:
$$
\begin{align}
  \Sigma \, \Sigma^{T} = 
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
  \mathbf{S}^{2} & \mathbf{0} \\
  \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} 
\end{array} \right]_{m\times m},  \qquad
%
  \Sigma^{T} \, \Sigma &= 
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
  \mathbf{S}^{2} & \mathbf{0} \\
  \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} 
\end{array} \right]_{n\times n}
%
\end{align}
$$
Third step:
$$
\begin{align}
  \Sigma \, \Sigma^{+} = 
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
  \mathbf{I}_{\rho} & \mathbf{0} \\
  \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} 
\end{array} \right]_{m\times m},  \qquad
%
  \Sigma^{+} \, \Sigma &= 
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
  \mathbf{I}_{\rho} & \mathbf{0} \\
  \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} 
\end{array} \right]_{n\times n}
%
\end{align}
$$
Fourth step:
$$
\begin{align}
  \Sigma \, \Sigma^{+} \, \Sigma &= 
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
  \mathbf{S} & \mathbf{0} \\
  \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} 
\end{array} \right]_{m\times n} = \Sigma,  \qquad
%
 \Sigma^{+} \,  \Sigma \,  \Sigma^{+} = 
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
  \mathbf{S} & \mathbf{0} \\
  \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} 
\end{array} \right]_{n\times m} = \Sigma^{+}
%
\end{align}
$$

---

**a**

$$
\begin{align}
 \mathbf{A} \, \mathbf{A}^{+} \, \mathbf{A} &=
% A
\left( 
\mathbf{U} \, \Sigma \, \mathbf{V}^{*}
\right)
% A
\left( 
\mathbf{V} \, \Sigma^{+} \, \mathbf{U}^{*}
\right)
% A+
\left( 
\mathbf{U} \, \Sigma \, \mathbf{V}^{*}
\right) \\
%
& = \mathbf{U} \, \Sigma \, \Sigma^{+} \, \Sigma \, \mathbf{V}^{*} \\
%
& = \mathbf{U} \, \Sigma \, \mathbf{V}^{*} \\
%
& = \mathbf{A}
%
\end{align}
$$

**b**

$$
\begin{align}
 \mathbf{A}^{+} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{A}^{+}
& = \mathbf{V} \, \Sigma^{+} \, \Sigma \, \Sigma^{+} \, \mathbf{U}^{*} \\
& = \mathbf{V} \, \Sigma^{+} \, \mathbf{U}^{*} \\
%
& = \mathbf{A}^{+}
%
\end{align}
$$

**c**

$$
\begin{align}
 \left( \mathbf{A} \, \mathbf{A}^{+} \right)^{*} &=
% A
\left( 
\mathbf{U} \, \Sigma \,  \Sigma^{+}  \, \mathbf{U}^{*}
\right)^{*} \\
% A
&=
\left( 
\mathbf{U} \, 
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
  \mathbf{I}_{\rho} & \mathbf{0} \\
  \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} 
\end{array} \right]
  \, \mathbf{U}^{*}
\right)^{*} \\
&=
\mathbf{U} \, 
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
  \mathbf{I}_{\rho} & \mathbf{0} \\
  \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} 
\end{array} \right]
  \, \mathbf{U}^{*} \\
&=  \mathbf{A} \, \mathbf{A}^{\dagger}
%
\end{align}
$$

**d**

$$
\begin{align}
 \left( \mathbf{A}^{+} \, \mathbf{A} \right)^{*} &=
% A
\left( 
\mathbf{V} \, \Sigma^{+} \,  \Sigma  \, \mathbf{V}^{*}
\right)^{*} \\
% A
&=
\mathbf{V} \, 
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
  \mathbf{I}_{\rho} & \mathbf{0} \\
  \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} 
\end{array} \right]
  \, \mathbf{V}^{*} \\
&=  \mathbf{A}^{+} \, \mathbf{A}
%
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that the SVD definition of the pseudo-inverse is 
$$
A^+ = V\Sigma^+U^*$$
where the SVD of $A$ is $A=U\Sigma V^*$ and 
$\Sigma^+$ is a diagonal matrix with diagonal entries 
$$[\Sigma^+]_{ii}=\left\{ \begin{array} 00 
 & \text{if} [\Sigma]_{ii}=0\\
([\Sigma]_{ii})^{-1}&\text{otherwise}\end{array}\right.$$

It's then just a matter of plugging in the SVD of $A$ and $A^{+}$ into the equations (a)-(d).  For example for (a) you have
$$
AA^{+}A=(U\Sigma V^*)(V\Sigma^{+}U^*)(U\Sigma V^*)=U\Sigma\Sigma^+\Sigma V^*=U\Sigma V^*=A $$
$$

Comment: How would the transpose be used in this?

Comment: According to wikipedia the transposes should be conjugate transposes (Hermitian transpose), but when the matrices are real these can be changed to transposes.